# Recursive scan for ACLs on directories with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, permissions, acl

I was curious about something. I'm writing a piece of code with C++ that needs to scan ACL permissions on subfolders of a specific folder and find those that differ from the ACL permissions of the first folder. To do that I recursively check all folders within the folder, using [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then check ACL permissions by calling [GetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on each subfolder found.

This method works, except that it works very slow, especially when scanning network shares. I know that the tool called [accesschk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx) can do the same thing, but when I run it recursively on the same folder (with `-dsqvli` switches) it returns the result way quicker than my procedure I described above.

So I was wondering how can I speed up this ACL permissions look up process?

My first thought was to use inheritance on ACEs, I'm just not sure how to implement it...

**EDIT 2:** Thanks @arx for suggestions. This ACL/ACE stuff is very poorly documented. The code he posted below worked for me. Note that my original code for checking ACL inheritance did not produce reliable results due to the reason's @arx outlined below in his post.

Comment: If you run accesschk after you've run your tool it will always be quicker because all the information will be in cache.  If that's not the problem, profile your app.  It may be spending its time decoding ACLs (perhaps you're not caching SID lookups?) rather than actually retrieving security descriptors.  It may be spending time outputting lots of text to the console because (unlike accesschk) it's not ignoring inheritable ACEs.  Or whatever.  Until you know where it's slow you can't hope to fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I agree. The problem is that I run into this issue on a client's machine (which does not have my development tools.) What can I use to profile the app there?

Comment: I don't know of a profiling tool that produces a standalone instrumented app that you could run on a client machine.  Maybe a question for SO.

Comment: @arx: I did do some profiling. It turns out that if I call `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` API to check each folder's ACL permissions it takes almost 90% of the overall time. What is the method to see if a folder inherits ACEs from a parent folder and thus not check its ACL permissions?

Comment: There's no particular reason for GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl to be slow unless you are calling it far too often (i.e. many times per directory) or you are identifying trustees by name.  The latter would be very slow.

Comment: How else would I identify a trustee?

Comment: I'm using `BuildTrusteeWithSid` to create a trustee. This happens before the recursive search, so it's called only once. Then I call `GetNamedSecurityInfo` on each directory found (may be up to a thousand times, or whatever the number of subdirectories) to get folders' DACL and then it, along with the `TRUSTEE` struct is used for the call to `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`. If I comment out the `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` API I get a tremendous boost is speed.

Comment: Presumably you're using a user SID.  It hadn't occurred to me before but `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` needs to determine which groups the user is a member of.  I guess this is cached for a logged-on user, but for other users it might require a round-trip to the domain server.  You could try calling the function a million times in a loop (on the same ACL) while running procmon to see what it's doing.  If this is the problem you could determine the user's group membership before starting the recursion then write your own version of `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what would be the steps (APIs) of writing my own version of `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`?

Comment: I'm leaving in ten minutes so this is a bit rushed.  But something like: initialize two access bit masks to zero - one for rights that have been denied, and one for rights that have been granted.  Enumerate the ACEs in the ACL (using GetAce).  If an ACE applies to your user or any of its groups then OR the access mask with either the denied or granted mask (depending on the ACE type).  Once you've processed all the ACEs, mask off the denied mask from the granted mask (i.e. `granted & ~denied`).  This is rather complicated because there are lots of ACE types.

Comment: Actually, it's slightly simpler than that.  Process the ACEs in reverse order and you only need to keep one access bit mask (initially zero).  Add bits to it for allowed ACEs, and remove bits for denied ACEs.  I really must go.

Comment: So what about ACL's inheritance. Won't it be easier to check if it's inherited and if so, not to bother with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some further information from the comments:

The application determines the SID of a user whose access rights are being checked.

Having called `GetNamedSecurityInfo` on each directory, the application calls `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` with the SID of the user.  It is the latter call that is taking most of the time.

`GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` checks the ACL against the user's SID and the SIDs of any groups the user is a member of.  It is likely slow because determining a user's groups requires a round trip to the domain controller.

There are two possible fixes and a dead end:

**Emulate GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl**

Outside the loop, determine the SID of the user and the SIDs of the user's groups.  (TODO: Check if nested groups are handled automatically, or if they must be resolved recursively.)

To determine the effective rights for an ACL:

1. Use an ACCESS_MASK (actually a DWORD) to represent the rights mask.  Initialize it to zero.
2. Process the ACEs in the ACL in reverse order.  This ensures that earlier ACEs take precedence.
3. If an ACE refers to any of the previously determined SIDs then, for access-allowed ACEs OR the ACE's mask with your rights mask and for access-denied ACEs mask off the ACE's mask from your rights mask.

Once you've processed all the ACEs your rights mask holds the answer.

**Skip Inherited ACLs**

In many directory hierarchies most or all of the files and directories will inherit their permissions from their parents.  However, this doesn't help.  Inherited ACLs may not be active on the parent, so the effective rights of the children won't match the effective rights of the parent.  So an ACL still has to be checked even if it inherited.

**Cache the result of GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl**

Simply create a map from ACLs to effective rights masks.  To do this you need a way of comparing ACLs.  You can't just compare entire ACLs using memcmp because ACL.AclSize includes the size of extra padding.  Instead, compare the number of ACEs, and if they are the same compare the individual ACEs using memcmp.

I tried this on my `Program Files` directory.  Scanning the whole directory structure required 6 calls to `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`.  The remaining 2,708 directories were resolved from the cache so it was much faster.

The following implements a cached version of `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`.  Note that error-handling is lacking, and it never frees the PACLs it puts in the map.

```
// Compare two access-control lists.
// Return <0 if acl1<acl2, 0 if acl1==acl2 and >0 if acl1>acl2.
// The ordering is arbitrary but consistent.
int aclcmp(PACL acl1, PACL acl2)
{
    // First compare by number of ACEs
    int c = acl1->AceCount - acl2->AceCount;
    if (c)
        return c;

    // We have the same number of ACEs, so compare each ACE
    int aceCount = acl1->AceCount;
    for (int aceIndex = 0; aceIndex != aceCount; ++aceIndex)
    {
        // Get the ACEs
        PACE_HEADER ace1;
        PACE_HEADER ace2;
        GetAce(acl1, aceIndex, (LPVOID*)&ace1);
        GetAce(acl2, aceIndex, (LPVOID*)&ace2);
        // Compare the ACE sizes
        c = ace1->AceSize - ace2->AceSize;
        if (c)
            return c;

        // Compare the ACE content
        c = memcmp(ace1, ace2, ace1->AceSize);
        if (c)
            return c;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Less-than operator for pointers to ACLs
class ComparePAcl
{
public:
    bool operator()(const PACL& acl1, const PACL& acl2) const
    {
        return aclcmp(acl1, acl2) < 0;
    }
};

// Map from pointers-to-ACLs to access masks
typedef std::map<PACL, ACCESS_MASK, ComparePAcl> AclToAccessMask;
AclToAccessMask aclToAccessMask;

// Just to check how the cache performs
DWORD foundCount = 0;
DWORD notFoundCount = 0;

// Same as GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl but caches results.
// Note that this must be called with the same trustee to get meaningful results.
DWORD CachedGetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(PACL pacl, PTRUSTEE pTrustee, PACCESS_MASK pAccessRights)
{
    AclToAccessMask::const_iterator it = aclToAccessMask.find(pacl);
    if (it != aclToAccessMask.end())
    {
        // The ACL is in the cache
        ++foundCount;
        *pAccessRights = it->second;
    }
    else
    {
        // The ACL is not in the cache
        ++notFoundCount;
        DWORD rc = GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(pacl, pTrustee, pAccessRights);
        if (rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            return rc;
        // TODO: Clean up copies of ACLs afterwards
        PACL aclcopy = (PACL)malloc(pacl->AclSize);
        memcpy(aclcopy, pacl, pacl->AclSize);
        aclToAccessMask.insert(AclToAccessMask::value_type(aclcopy, *pAccessRights));
    }

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I appreciate your help! I updated my original post with the code sample. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind.  Is it working for you, i.e. is it skipping subfolders as expected?

Comment: It sure runs faster. Without the inheritance check I get about 7 seconds and with it -- about 1 sec. The issue I'm trying to overcome is the access mask for an inherited ACL. If it is inherited where does the access mask come from?

Comment: Yeah, there's something missing in that approach. For instance, if I recursively search on my `C:\Program Files` folder, its access mask initially is `0x1200A9`. Then I have the `C:\Program Files\Far\Addons` folder that without my inheritance check gets access mask of `0x1F01FF` from `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` API, but with my inheritance check procedure it becomes `inherited` and thus its access mask is skipped (although it is different)...

Comment: Sorry.  You suggested doing something with inherited ACLs, so I explained how to, but I didn't think it through.  It isn't actually much use.  I explain why in the answer.  I've also posted code (not production ready) to implement a cache round `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`.  This provides a huge performance improvement on my computer, which isn't attached to a domain.  I'd expect the improvement to more marked if there is a DC involved.

Comment: I want to thank you again for your help. The method of caching the data worked for me as well. I also edited out my inheritance check code because it doesn't really work. One follow-up question though. The msdn page for `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446637(v=vs.85).aspx has a code sample at the bottom where they use `AuthzAccessCheck` API to get the access rights. Are you familiar with that approach of getting ACLs? I'm curious why not just call `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` instead?

Comment: Just in case you didn't see it, I added a comment to the code after I posted it pointing out that, as it stands, it only works for a single SID.  I'd never noticed the Authz API before.  It seems to fix exactly the problem you've got!  `AuthzInitializeContextFromSid` does the group lookups, so the actual access check shouldn't require a network round trip (which is the problem with `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl`).  So it should be a lot faster.